# how to use NodeJS to modify a file and save to a new one?

Tags: node.js

I have a plain text file named `source.txt`

I want to use a NodeJS script to do something to modify the content of the txt file and save as a new file, say `output.txt`

How do I do that?

I am expecting a command-line implementation, something like:

`$node modify.js source.txt output.txt`

Thanks!

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: @r3mus Thanks, worked! One more question: There is a `callback` for `fs.open()`. On the API Doc it says `The callback gets two arguments (err, fd).` Is there any reference for all the possible `err` and `fd` values?

Comment: No reference that I know of, however you can just try/catch on err and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Node.js's build in [`fs()`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) function to read and write files to the local filesystem.

Basic read example:

```
fs.readFile('source.txt', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
});
```

Basic write example:

```
fs.writeFile('output.txt', 'Hello Node', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('It\'s saved!');
});
```

**Note:** ensure your Node instance (and the account it's being run under) has appropriate permissions to the read and write source/destination.

Comment: Thanks very much! However, the output of `console.log(data)` is something like: `<Buffer 65 73 74>`, what is the meaning? How do I get the rawdata? What if the content has some special characters (like Chinese, Japanese characters)?

Comment: Just append `.toString()` to convert the stream to text ;)

Answer (score 4):

Sync style:

```
// save as: uppercase.js

var fs = require('fs');

var input = process.argv[2];
var output = process.argv[3];

var content = fs.readFileSync(input, 'utf8');
content = content.toUpperCase();    
fs.writeFileSync(output, content);
```

Run:

```
$node uppercase source.txt output.txt
```